Retrieve all files of a folder from sharepoint
I'm trying to download all files from my sharepoint using
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Folder Name')/Files

Here is my code which makes the call :
public static HttpResponse getFiles(){
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
            request.setEndpoint('https://<subdomain>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(\''+'/sites/<site-name>/Documents%20partages/General/CRM%20Dynamics%20Attachment'+'\')/files');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
            request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AccountTriggerHandler.getSharepointAccessToken() );
            System.debug('***** httpRequestToSend-->' + request);
            HttpResponse responseJSON = http.send(request);
            System.debug('------------ JSON RESPONSE ------- :'+responseJSON);
            System.debug('------------ JSON RESPONSE ------- :'+JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseJSON.getBody()));

            return null;
        }

Here is the error I have :
System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

I already tried to do the same with Postman, I have the same error code.
Do you know what am I missing ?
Thanks

This looks like a question about Sharepoint and not Salesforce. Are you sure you're asking in the right place?

Have you done some basic troubleshooting like trying the request with Postman or curl?  Please [edit] your post and include those details.
